# How to prevent member QWidgets or QDialog objects taking over key events from QMainWindow once the dialog has been clicked by the mouse?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, keyevent, qdialog

So I have `QMainWindow` type class which described by the following code:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    void closeEvent(QCloseEvent *);\
    DimensionDialog *newResolution;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    ImageInteraction *liveVideo;
    ImageInteraction *modifiedVideo;
    CameraControl *cameraControl;
    QPushButton *pushToTalk;
    QPushButton *audioSettingsSetup;
    AudioSettings *audioSettings;
    QPushButton *numberOfRunningThreads;

protected:
    void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event);
    void keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent * event);

private slots:
    void restartVideoWithNewResolution(int, int);
};
```

From there you can see that this class does handle some key events.

As you can see, this class also has members `DimensionDialog` and `CameraControl`, which are respectively `QDialog` and `QWigdet` type classes. Now, these two members have their own slots as well, which are called when certain buttons are pressed. The problem is that when one of these buttons are pressed, the corresponding class (either `DimesionDialog` or `CameraControl`) takes over the key events and the `MainWindow` class cannot catch any more of the key events.

I cannot understand why it's happening. How do I prevent this? I want key event to be handled only by the `MainWindow`.

Thanks.

Comment: did you play with grabKeyboard? http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#grabKeyboard

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about it. It's helping.

Comment: Use  [installEventFilter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) to prevent dialog from receiving this event and then dispatched to your mainwindow.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to propagate key event to parent you should ignore it explicitly.

```
void DimensionDialog:keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    // ...
    // do something then propagate event to parent
    event->ignore();
}
```

It is QEvent's behaviour. So, for mouse events it should work as well.

If you need to detect key events globally in the whole application then you can catch and process them in reimplemented QApplication::notify() (for more details how to use QCoreApplication::notify() see Qt docs on that).

```
class KeyEventAwareApp : public QApplication
{
  public:
    using QApplication::QApplication;

    bool notify(QObject* object,QEvent* event)
    {
      if(event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
      {
        // do any event processing here, for example redirect it to other object
        // if swallow event then
        return true;
        // otherwise send event to the receiver
        return object->event(event);
      }
      // we are interested only in key events, so forward the rest to receivers
        return object->event(event);
    }
};
```

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't work. grabKeyboard only to have the control of keyboard with the MainWindow, but then the key events don't work for other widgets when they are open on top of the MainWindow.

Comment: I see. The DimensionDialog might be a top level window rather than a child of QMainWIndow, event propagation then won't work. Then what you need is to grab key events globally at QApplication level and then send them for processing to some of your methods in your main window. I'll edit the post.